# Programming practice: the price of laptops list problem

Tags: python

This is the question that given to me

> One day Sindakht and Irsa were discussing the price of laptops and their quality. Sindakht guesses that the more expensive a laptop is, the better the quality. But Irsa claims that she can find 2 laptops whose price is lower than the first, but its quality is higher than the second, and she can refute Sindakht's guess. Now you have to write a program to help Irsa investigate her claim.
>
> N laptop specifications will be given to you. The first input line contains the number n, which indicates the number of laptops. Each of the next n lines contains two numbers, the first of which indicates the price of the laptop and the second of which indicates the quality of the laptop. If you can find two laptops that meet the conditions stated by Irsa, print happy irsa, otherwise print poor irsa (please note the lower case letters, all letters are written in lower case).
>
> Sample input:
>
> ```
> 2 
> 1 10 
> 7 3
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> ```
> happy irsa
> ```
>
> At the input of the sample, the first laptop is priced at 1 and the quality is 10 (the higher the number, the higher the quality). The second laptop is priced at 7 and the quality is 3. Well, Irsa has managed to find two laptops, which although the price of the latter is higher than the price of the first, but the quality of the latter is lower than the quality of the first.
>
> Sample input:
>
> ```
> 4 
> 1 5 
> 7 9 
> 5 6 
> 20 30
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> ```
> poor irsa
> ```

and I try this Anyone can help me to make it Right

```
n=int(input())
computer=[]

for m in range(n) :
    laptop=input()
    laptop=laptop.split()
    computer.append(laptop)

for i in range(n) :
    for j in range(2):
        computer[i][j]=int(computer[i][j])

for i in range(n+1) :
    if computer[i][0] < computer[i+1][0] and computer[i][1] > computer[i+1][1] :
        print("happy irsa")
        break
    else:
        print("poor irsa")
        break
```

Comment: Please explain (in the question) why you believe your current output is not right.  And, provide your current input/output.

Comment: You're always breaking on the first iteration of the loop, so you're only testing the first pair of laptops, not every pair.

Comment: And even without that, you're not comparing every pair of laptops, you're only comparing laptop i with laptop i+1. You'll also go out of range with `i` reaches the last laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare every pair of laptops, so you need nested loops.

You should only break out of the loop when you find a pair that makes Irsa happy. If you end without breaking, Irsa is sad, you can use the `else:` blocb for this.

```
irsa_happy = False

for c1 in computer:
    for c2 in computer:
        if c1[0] < c2[0] and c1[1] > c2[1]:
            print("happy irsa")
            irsa_happy = True
            break
    if irsa_happy:
        break
else:
    print("poor irsa")
```